# Fixtures many to one symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, fixtures, many-to-one

Despite all my research, I can not achieve my fixtures with manyToOne relationship

I would like to separate my fixtures as I will need them in many cases. Is this good practice?

**Class Territory**

```
Entity Territory
{
    private $id;
    private $department; 
}
```

**Class User**

```
Entity User
{
    private $id;
    private $name; 
    
    @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Territory")
    private $territory_id
}
```

**TerritoryFixtures**

```
class TerritoryFixtures extends Fixture
{

    public const TERRITORIES = 'territories';
    //public $territories = [];

        $datas = [
            [1, 'AAA'],
            [5, 'BBB'],
            [8, 'CCC'],
        ];


        foreach ($datas as $k => $data) {
            $territory[$k] = new Territory();
            $territory[$k]->setId($datas[$k][0]) // i need
                ->setDepartment($datas[$k][1]);

            $manager->persist($territoire[$k]);

            $this->addReference(self::TERRITORIES, $territory[$k]);  // only the last datas
            // $this->addReference($this->territories, $territory[$k]);
        }
        $manager->flush();
}
```

**UserFixtures**

```
class UserFixtures extends Fixture implements DependentFixtureInterface
{
    public function getDependencies()
    {
        return [
            TerritoryFixtures::class
        ];
    }

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $territories = $this->getReference(TerritoryFixtures::TERRITORIES);
        // **step 1: how to recover all my territories**

        $faker = Factory::create();

        for ($a = 0; $a < 10; $a++) {

            $user = new User();

            // **step 2 : how to insert a territory entity randomly**
            $user->setDepartement($faker->randomElement($territories))
                ->setName($faker->lastName());

}
```

In summary :

1. generate a territory object
2. give this 'Territory' object to the UserFixtures
3. Randomly insert a territory to the user

Is it possible ? I block despite all my attempts

Comment: Yes, that looks like good practise. What **exactly** is not working? What have you tried to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

```
//public $territories = [];
```

Should be

```
$territory = [];
```

And

```
$manager->persist($territoire[$k]);
```

Should be

```
$manager->persist($territory[$k]);
```

According to the rest of your code.

If that doesn't solve your problem you'll have to tell us what error you are getting and what you tried to solve it.